# Finding the median of a range of values from one column based on the value of another

Tags: r

My friend and I have been racking our brains about how to find the median from the following example data-set:

```
A <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15) #15 minute intervals
B <- c(4.1, 3.3, 11.7, 3.9, 2.9, 3.6, 4.8, 3.5, 5.0, 4.4, 4.9, 9.9, 8.5, 11.0, 14.0) #Blood glucose mmolperL
C <- c(NA, NA, 130, NA, NA, NA, NA, 115, NA, NA, NA, 120, NA, NA, NA) #Systolic Blood pressure
DF <- cbind(A,B,C)
```

From the above data-set we wish to know the median blood glucose value (Column B) around the time which systolic (Column C) was taken. The problem is that the first blood glucose reading (11.7) in the same row as the reading for systolic blood pressure (130), is quite different to the other readings around this time-point.

We wish to take the data-points for blood glucose around this 11.7 value and compute a median and assign it to the corresponding blood pressure.

!!OF NOTE!! this is one example data-set from one experiment. In other experiments the time-intervals are not as neat and so we can't use a regular subset criteria based on column A. The real data-frame is also a lot, lot larger, with the a greater number of rows between blood pressure readings. I simplified the data-frame for this example.

Comment: It would be helpful if you were more explicit here in what you want. You talk about taking the median of column B around the time when there is a measurement in column C without actually saying what this means. Within a certain time window? Something else? It would help to give your desired output for your sample input.

Comment: When you say "around"... Do you mean time-wise or concentration-wise?

Comment: Can you create a data frame with the output you would like to see to make it more clear what you are after?

Comment: Dear All

Thanks for reviewing my question. Jaap managed to answer the question below but next time I will also add an example answer as it would be great to have as much input as possible from the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though @Jaap has provided a very good solution to the original problem. I was still trying to find a way to without using `aggregate`.

I wanted to consider `previous`, `next` and current reading of the `B` (for which `C` contains valid value) to calculate `median`.

```
    library(dplyr)
    DF %>%
      mutate(lag_B = lag(B), lead_B = lead(B)) %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(median_B = ifelse(is.na(C), NA_integer_,median(c(lag_B, B, lead_B))) ) %>%
      select(A, B, C, median_B)

Results:
# A tibble: 15 x 4
#       A     B     C median_B
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1  1.00  4.10    NA    NA   
# 2  2.00  3.30    NA    NA   
# 3  3.00 11.7    130     3.90
# 4  4.00  3.90    NA    NA   
# 5  5.00  2.90    NA    NA   
# 6  6.00  3.60    NA    NA   
# 7  7.00  4.80    NA    NA   
# 8  8.00  3.50   115     4.80
# 9  9.00  5.00    NA    NA   
#10 10.0   4.40    NA    NA   
#11 11.0   4.90    NA    NA   
#12 12.0   9.90   120     8.50
#13 13.0   8.50    NA    NA   
#14 14.0  11.0     NA    NA   
#15 15.0  14.0     NA    NA
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @MarkGraham Welcome. Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
w <- which(!is.na(DF$C))

DF[w, 'B'] <- aggregate(B ~ rep(1:length(w), each = 3), DF[rep(w, each = 3) + c(-1,0,1),], median)$B
```

which gives:

> ```
> > DF
>     A    B   C
> 1   1  4.1  NA
> 2   2  3.3  NA
> 3   3  3.9 130
> 4   4  3.9  NA
> 5   5  2.9  NA
> 6   6  3.6  NA
> 7   7  4.8  NA
> 8   8  4.8 115
> 9   9  5.0  NA
> 10 10  4.4  NA
> 11 11  4.9  NA
> 12 12  8.5 120
> 13 13  8.5  NA
> 14 14 11.0  NA
> 15 15 14.0  NA
> ```

What this does:

- `w <- which(!is.na(DF$C))` creates an index `w` where `C` is not NA.
- With `aggregate` you can calculate the `median` for the needed rows. In this case I chose to take only the row itself and the row before and after the row where `C` has a value.
- `DF[rep(w, each = 3) + c(-1,0,1),]` filters `DF` to only the needed rows
- `rep(1:length(w), each = 3)` creates a grouping vector for `aggregate`
- The result is assigned back to the `B`-column for the rownumbers in `w`.

---

You can also use this logic with the `data.table`-package:

```
# load the 'data.table'-package and convert 'DF' to a data.table with 'setDF'
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

# create two indexes:
# 'i1' for when 'C' has a value
# 'i2' which includes the previous and the next row for each value in 'i1'
i1 <- DF[, .I[!is.na(C)]]
i2 <- rep(i1, each = 3)

# replace 'B' by reference with the median
DF[i1, B := DF[i2 + -1:1, median(B), i2]$V1][]
```

---

Because the actual data is a lot larger (as stated in the question) it is worthwile to test the different solutions on a much larger dataset.

First, let's create a big dataset that mimics the original `DF` from the question:

```
DFbig <- DF[sample(nrow(DF), 1e7, TRUE),]
setDT(DFbig)
i <- DFbig[, .I[!is.na(C) & (!is.na(shift(C, type = 'lag')) | !is.na(shift(C, type = 'lead')))]]
d <- c(2L,diff(i))
i <- i[d > 1]
DFbig2 <- DFbig[!i]
```

The timings for the base R solution:

```
DFtest <- as.data.frame(DFbig2)

system.time(
  {w <- which(!is.na(DFtest$C)); DFtest[w, 'B'] <- aggregate(B ~ rep(1:length(w), each = 3), DFtest[rep(w, each = 3) + c(-1,0,1),], median)$B}
)
```

> ```
>    user  system elapsed 
>  52.049   0.997  53.084
> ```

The timings for the `dplyr` solution:

```
DFtest <- as.data.frame(DFbig2)

system.time(
  DFtest %>% mutate(lag_B = lag(B), lead_B = lead(B)) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(B = ifelse(is.na(C), NA_integer_, median(c(lag_B, B, lead_B))) ) %>% select(A, B, C)
)
```

> ```
>    user  system elapsed 
> 174.725   1.652 176.721
> ```

The timings for the `data.table` solution:

```
DFtest <- copy(DFbig2)

system.time(
  {i1 <- DFtest[, .I[!is.na(C)]]; i2 <- rep(i1, each = 3); DFtest[i1, B := DFtest[i2 + -1:1, median(B), i2]$V1][]}
)
```

> ```
>    user  system elapsed 
>   0.300   0.057   0.359
> ```

As is quite clear from the test results: the `data.table`-solution is the fastest, followed by the base R solution and while the `dplyr`-solution is by far the slowest.

---

Used data:

```
DF <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15),
                 B = c(4.1, 3.3, 11.7, 3.9, 2.9, 3.6, 4.8, 3.5, 5.0, 4.4, 4.9, 9.9, 8.5, 11.0, 14.0),
                 C = c(NA, NA, 130, NA, NA, NA, NA, 115, NA, NA, NA, 120, NA, NA, NA))
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much for taking the time to help us out

Comment: @MarkGraham May I ask why you unaccepted my answer?

Comment: @MarkGraham I've updated my answer with a `data.table`-solution and a benchmark of the different solutions